# Is there a way to check if any radio button has been clicked in a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a form and I want the text of a button to change depending on if any radio button in the whole form has been clicked on, additionally some radio buttons are in group boxes so do not affect other radio buttons. The only way I can think of to do this is to input code into every method that is called for when each radio button is clicked. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Controls have events you can listen to and act upon. I would start by looking at the documentation.. This is your mission if you choose to accept it

Comment: You might also want to tag this question with the forms framework you are using (`[WinForms]`, `[WPF]`, `[ASP.NET Web Forms]`, etc.). And, the way this site works best is that you post your code, point out your issues, and someone provides an answer to address them. Without any code, your question is unlikely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create one method for click event for one radioButton only and make all radioButtons share this click event and i will suppose that you will make Button text like radioButton text which you clicked and inside this method write this line...

```
private void radioButton1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) {
    button1.Text = (RadioButton(sender)).Text;
}
```